# Sort the odd numbers in the list

Tags: python

How can I sort ascending the odd numbers in a list of integers, but leaving the even numbers in their original places?

Example:

```
sortArray([5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4]) == [1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 4]
```

My code:

```
def sort_array(source_array):     
    odd_numbers = [n for n in source_array if n%2!=0]
    odd_numbers = sorted(odd_numbers)
```

How do I switch the indices of the odd numbers in `source_array` with the ones in `odd_numbers`?

Comment: This is an interesting little puzzle. But you should post your own attempt at coding this, and explain where you're stuck.

Comment: Lazy version: go once through the input array and record odd numbers together with their positions. Then sort the odd numbers. Then overwrite them in the input array.

Comment: def sort_array(source_array):
     
    odd_numbers = [n for n in source_array if n%2!=0]
    odd_numbers = sorted(odd_numbers)
    
i don't know how to switch indexes of odd numbers in my source array with indexes of odd_numbers

Answer (score 15):

Looks like you're almost there - you can make your sorted odd numbers an iterable and re-build your source list with either the original even number or the next sorted odd number, eg:

```
>>> data = [5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4]
>>> odds = iter(sorted(el for el in data if el % 2))
>>> [next(odds) if el % 2 else el for el in data]
[1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 5):

More lines but also more readable

```
a = [5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4]
b = sorted([item for item in a if item%2 != 0])
odd_int = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] %2 != 0:
        a[i] = b[odd_int]
        odd_int += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using numpy, you can get the indices of odd numbers using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), sort the odd numbers and update the array using the previously obtained indices assigning to the sorted array of odd numbers:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4])
ind = np.where(a%2)                 # get indices of odd items
a[ind] = np.sort(a[ind])            # update items at indices using sorted array
print(a)
# array([1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sort_array(source_array):
    odd_numbers = sorted([n for n in source_array if n%2!=0])
    c = 0
    res = []
    for i in source_array:
        if i %2!=0:
            res.append(odd_numbers[c])
            c += 1
        else:
            res.append(i)
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sort_array(source_array):
    sorted_array = [i for i in source_array if i % 2 != 0]
    sorted_array.sort()
    for index, item in enumerate(source_array):
        if item % 2 == 0:
            sorted_array.insert(index, item)
    return sorted_array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sort_array(arr):
  odds = sorted((x for x in arr if x%2 != 0), reverse=True)
  return [x if x%2==0 else odds.pop() for x in arr]
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, the **how** is important, but a great part of the quality level of the site comes from the fact that people go to great lengths to explain the **why**. While a _code-only_ answer get the person who asked the question past whatever hurdle they might be facing, it doesn't do them or future visitors much good in the long run. See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937)

Comment: Also, this is basically the same as John Clements' answer.

Answer (score -4):

You can get the result you want by iterating over the length of the array and performing a sort only on the items that are odd, which can be determined by modulus division. This algorithm utilizes Bubblesort, which is inefficient, but can operate as a working example of the principal.

```
public static int[] SortArray(int[] array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < array.Length; j++)
        {
            if (array[i] % 2 == 1 && array[j] % 2 == 1 && array[i] > array[j])
            {
                var por = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = por;
            }
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?