# Assign list values to dictionary keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So I want to loop over a dictionary and a list simultaneously without them being nested.
What I really mean is:

```
for i,c in enumerate(dictionary) and for k in range(len(list)):
       dictionary[c] = list[k]
```

So it basically loops over one dictionary and I can assign values to the dictionary with a list.

Comment: You want to be careful when enumerating a dictionary, since dictionary is not ordered before python 3.6. And what do you need enumerate for since you never used "i"?

Comment: I did use ‘i’, just didn’t mention the use in the example here.

Comment: Are the dictionary and the list the same size?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of toy inputs and the expected output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IIUC, you are trying to reassign existing keys to list values. This is something you can only do from python-3.7 onwards (or 3.6 if you use CPython). This can be done either through direct reassignment,

```
dictionary = dict(zip(dictionary, lst))
```

Or, if they are not the same length, and there are keys you want to preserve, use `dict.update`:

```
dictionary.update(dict(zip(dictionary, lst)))
```

Additionally, it is unwise to name variables after builtin objects (such as `list`).

Comment: `{k:v for k,v in <whatever>}` should probably just be `dict(<whatever>)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks. I wanted it to be explicit, but I've added the shorter version as well.

Comment: @coldspeed not sure this is what OP is looking for. Based on code, OP wants to have old keys mapped to items in list. But it's not that clear in OP.

Comment: @Tim The problem with that is that dictionaries aren't ordered. So unless its clear how the list maps to the dictionary, I'm hesitant to change my answer.

Comment: @coldspeed I agree, it's not clear how the map should work. Maybe dict is not the right structure for this job at all. But I just read that dict are ordered in python 3.6+. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6

Comment: @Tim Thanks. I am aware, but the question is tagged "python", so there's nothing to suggest that OP is working with ordered dictionaries. I feel like it would be wrong to assume unless they say so.

Comment: @coldspeed agreed

Comment: @coldspeed Ok so what I want to do is I’ve got a list with both odd and even numbers, and I want to sort all odd numbers without changing the position of even numbers. I update a dictionary with the index and value as a key-value pair and add all the odd numbers to a different list and sort them.

Comment: [Contd.] now I want to iterate over both the dictionary and list and update the indices with corresponding values in the list. I hope you understand.

Comment: I know there are better approaches to this but I wanted to understand how do(can) we do this. Also, Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Trollsors You can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461172/sort-the-odd-numbers-in-the-list

Comment: @Trollsors Also, can you please update your question so it is more clear what you want to do?

Answer (score 4):

`zip` is your friend

```
dictionary.update(zip(dictionary, lst))
```