# why am I getting index out of range error, when all I am doing is iterating through the length of the list?

Tags: python, indexing

I am writing code to solve the following problem: given a list of integers, sort the odd integers and leave the even integers in their place in the list.

For example: [5, 8, 6, 3, 4]  =>  [3, 8, 6, 5, 4]

```
def sort_array(source_array):
    odd_number =[]
    for i in range(len(source_array)): 
        if source_array[i] %2 != 0: 
            odd_number.append(source_array[i])
            
    odd_number = sorted(odd_number)
    
    
    pointer = 0 
    while pointer<= len(odd_number): 
        for i in range(len(source_array)): 
            if source_array[i]%2!= 0: 
                source_array[i] = odd_number[pointer]
                pointer +=1 
                
    return source_array
```

I am getting a index is out of range error for the following code:

```
for i in range(len(source_array)): 
    if source_array[i]%2!= 0: 
        source_array[i] = odd_number[pointer]
```

But I can't see why this is! I have tried running the iteration on paper, and it seems fine to me, as 'i' takes values from the length of source array less one- so why does it throw an error?

Comment: while loop should be `while pointer< len(odd_number): `

Comment: [Sort the odd numbers in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461172/sort-the-odd-numbers-in-the-list) shows alternative methods for this.  Answer by ed Jon Clements for instance does the sorting in just two lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping while pointer is less or equal length of `odd_number`. You should loop while pointer is less, because length of the list is not an index of the last element of the list. Fixed code:

```
def sort_array(source_array):
    odd_number =[]
    for i in range(len(source_array)): 
        if source_array[i] %2 != 0: 
            odd_number.append(source_array[i])
            
    odd_number = sorted(odd_number)
    
    
    pointer = 0 
    while pointer< len(odd_number): 
        for i in range(len(source_array)): 
            if source_array[i]%2!= 0: 
                source_array[i] = odd_number[pointer]
                pointer +=1 
                
    return source_array
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `odd_number[pointer]`

```
while pointer<= len(odd_number):
```

in this line, `len(odd_number)` is `2` therefore the highest `pointer` can go is 2.

but the list `odd_number` only has 2 items in it.

therefore indexing to 2 gives you the error  `IndexError: list index out of range` as you are trying to call for `odd_number[2]`